# Why Pstricks loads some PGF files and is there a bug?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

In `pstricks.tex` (version of 2019-01-22), at the line 75, we read:

```
\ifx\pgfkeysloaded\endinput\else 
 \input pgfutil-common.tex
 \input pgfkeys.code.tex
 \input pgffor.code.tex
\fi
\let\pgfforeach\foreach
```

The test `\ifx\pgfkeysloaded\endinput` seems strange to me.
If Pstricks is loaded after Tikz, the file `pgfutil-common.tex` may be loaded twice. This may lead to incoherences: for example, the definition of `\pgfutil@raggedright` found in `pgfutil-common.tex` would erase the definition of `\pgfutil@raggedright` done in `pgfutil-latex.def` (it's not the same) when Tikz was loaded.

Shouldn't be `\relax` instead of `\endinput`?

Comment: I think it means: *if already loaded then do nothing; otherwise, input these files*.

Comment: Yes, but in `pgfkeys.code.tex`, I didn't found `\let\pgfkeysloaded=\endinput` but `\let\pgfkeysloaded=\relax`.

Comment: Looks odd, write to the maintainer.

Comment: I'll have a look at it ...

Comment: This is no longer valid for pstricks.tex version 2019-02-23. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Yes. The bug has been corrected. Should I close the question? How to do that ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is solved in the latest version of pstricks.